# Passing value entered by user in main() to another function using C

Tags: c, function

I am trying to write a C main() program with a function. the program asks for a character in main(), then passes it to a function which then prints the character entered and returns that character in uppercase to main(). In main() the new uppercase character is printed.

I am able to read the character and convert it to uppercase, but can't get it to print the entered character from the function "convert". Here is what the output should look like:[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlXkb.jpg). Following is what I have done so far. Any help appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char convert(char a1);

int main (void)
{
    char lower, upper;
    printf("Please enter a lowercase character: ");
    scanf("%c",&lower);

    upper = convert(lower);
    printf("(from main) Uppercase character: %c\n",upper);
    return(0);
}
char convert(char a1)
{
    char result;
    printf("Entered character: %c",lower); /*This statement is to be printed*/
    result = toupper(a1);
    return (result);
}
```

[Here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izl6f.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from priniting it?

Comment: What's your input and the observed output?

Comment: Note: `return` is not a function, but a statement. The parenthesis are deprecated as they can shadow a typo and make the statement look like a function. They are actually part of the expression and serve no purpose. Don't use them for simple expressions (for more complicated they can enhance readbility, though).

Comment: i'm not sure how to pass the entered character from main to convert. so convert can then be used to display the entered character.

Comment: Your output ([from the last screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Izl6f.jpg)) looks correct to me. What's wrong? If you want to print from `convert` instead of `main`, you can move the `printf` from main to `convert` (replacing the `upper` variable by `result`), putting that line just before the `return`, and you're done.

Comment: From your update, I see you're missing a `\n`. If you don't use `\n`, your output will be buffered and not printed immediately.

Comment: Better to post textual versions of your output than pictures of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add below line-1 and line-2 to your function `convert`:

```
char convert(char a1)
{
    char result;
    printf("Converting to uppercase ...\n");  // line-1
    printf("(from function) Entered character is: %c\n", a1);  // line-2
    result = toupper(a1);
    return (result);
}
```

output:

```
Please enter a lowercase character: t
Converting to uppercase ...
(from function) Entered character is: t
(from main) Uppercase character: T
```

Comment: ohhh I see,I wrote those two lines but I was trying to call the function again in main() to have that printed. didn't know you could do that. thank you!

Comment: You are using `upper = convert(lower);` in `main` to call `convert` function and passing the value of `lower` to this function. So, inside the function `convert`, you get a copy of value of `lower` in argument `a1` of this function.